# jquery drag and drop position

Tags: jquery

I hope somebody can help my problem. Now i am doing jquery drag and drop.
My problem is that when user drag and place the image to drop area. That drop area is like tree picture. So the drop area should be like tree picture. but now I can drop on rectangle area. I don't know how can I solve this one. Anyone help me please.

I use following coding.

```
 $j("#draggable").draggable({

                revert: function (dropped) {
                    var $jdraggable = $j(this),
                 hasBeenDroppedBefore = $jdraggable.data('hasBeenDropped'),
                 wasJustDropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "tree";
                    if (wasJustDropped) {
                        //centering with css
                        centerPopup();
                        //load popup
                        loadsharePopup();
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        if (hasBeenDroppedBefore) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $j("#tree").droppable({
                activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
                hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    //var Stoppos = $j(this).position();
                    //alert("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
                    var newPosX = ui.offset.left - $j(this).offset().left;
                    var newPosY = ui.offset.top - $j(this).offset().top;
                    //alert($j(this).offset().left);
                    $j("#txtPosX").val(newPosX);
                    $j("#txtPosY").val(newPosY);
                    //alert("STOP: \nLeft: "+ newPosX + "\nTop: " + newPosY);
                    $j(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
                    $j(ui.draggable).data('hasBeenDropped', true);
                }
            });
        });

<div id="tree">
                    <div id="draggable"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Where is your code and what have you tried?

Comment: I included my coding in above question.

Comment: thank u very much for yr answer. I will try with this

Comment: to whom you are saying thanks........
:D

Comment: I thank to some one who give me reference link http://jsfiddle.net/EsKKh/. And then he deleted this. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly then you'd probably want to use **area** tag to create a shape of a tree in which draggable element will be dropped.

Info on **area** could be found here: http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_image_maps.cfm

Example (witch simple coords):

```
<map id ="tree">
  <area shape ="poly" coords ="55,55,120,80,90,80,90,100,70,100,20,80,55,55"
  href ="LINK"
  alt="Mount Cook" />
</map>
```